# Is it possible to implement fading action bar with actionbarActivity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I want to implement fadeout action bar like google play store. 
I tried so many but it's not working for me.

I am using ActionBarActivity, Theme.AppCompat.Light style
i customized the actionbar.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your code as it is please?

Comment: Have you tried the [FadingActionBar](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar) library? If you have, what problem did you have using it?